# OpenCV Video not shown full size

Tags: python, opencv

My problem is **opencv runs and show my video not in its original size** (seems OpenCV shrinks the video little bit), effecting my region of interest.

How can OpenCV show the exact orginal size of my video? Below is my code and the difference of the video original size and what OpenCV display.

Code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_link")
while True:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if not ret:
      break
   cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
   key = cv2.waitKey(1)
   if key == 27:
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyWindow()
```

Original size:

[image]

OpenCV Video output size:

[image]

Comment: Opencv doesnt reduce the image size or sth, but if your screen resolution isnt high enough, the opencv imshow window will be cropped. Can you try to call cv2.namedWindow with appropriate flags for resizing the window, once before your while-loop?

Comment: Agree with Micka. Use the `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` flag, it allows you to adjust the image window.

Comment: what's the video's resolution? what's the green polygons you drew on the right half of the image?

Answer (score 1):

try this, good luck. Manually enter the height, and width of the camera feed.(edit: Dshow works only in WIN, if you have something else, use different solution)

```
import cv2

video="videolink"
height=1080 #for some reason, ANYTHING else works for my HD camera for example 1079..
width=1920

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue
    cv2.imshow('CameraFeed', image )
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
      break
cap.release()
```

Comment: 1920x1050 is not a normal size.  I believe you meant 1920x1080, but even so it's not safe to assume that every camera can do that.  And remember that `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` is Windows-only.

Comment: Ah, thx, yeah forgot about the DHOW only in Win. Ah fullHD is 1080? Thats explain that extra 30 lines or pixels in my other projects I was so confused about for about a year! :D

Comment: Chmm I tested it on my HD camera just now and width 1080 DONT work, but 1070 yes....strange. I quess I would loose that 10 pixels or think about other method.

Comment: What size do you get if you don't set them?  OpenCV usually chooses the best option on its own.

Comment: 640x480 for some reason...